# "Invariances" in multiplication decompositions of simple Lie group Representations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups

1. Let $u_i$ be an object in the fundamental of SU(2). Let $\bar u_i$ be an object in the anti-fundamental of SU(2). We can consider the objects combining several $u_i$ and $\bar u_i$, following the rule of representation (rep) of SU(2),
   we know that
   $$2 \otimes 2 =1 \oplus 3$$
   $$2 \otimes \bar 2 =1 \oplus 3$$
   so if we combine two of SU(2) fundamental or anti-fundamentals, say 
   $$u_a \otimes u_b = v_{ab} $$
   we can get a trivial representation of SU(2) (that is 1 in the above equations). The object $v_{ab}$ in this trivial rep 1 does not transform under SU(2).

   > We can say the object $v_{ab}$ in this trivial rep 1 is invariant under SU(2).

We can also get a nontrivial (adjoint) rep of SU(2) which is also a vector rep of SO(3) (that is the 3 in the above equations). The object $v_{ab}$ in this vector rep 3 of SO(3) does not transform under the full SU(2), but only under the SO(3).

> We can say the object $v_{ab}$ in this vector rep 3 of SO(3) is not invariant under the SO(3), nor in the full SU(2).
>
> My question: Which **subgroup** of SU(2) is this object [$v_{ab}$ in this vector rep 3 of SO(3)] **invariant** under? [Naively, it looks that it is a U(1) subgroup of SU(2). The $v_{ab}$ fixes a direction in SO(3), but is still a U(1) rotational degree of freedom within SO(3).] In particular, are there are some additional  finite subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

2. Let $w_i$ be an object in the fundamental of SU(3). Let $\bar w_i$ be an object in the anti-fundamental of SU(3).
   We know that
   $$3 \otimes 3 =\bar 3 \oplus 6$$
   $$3 \otimes \bar 3 =1 \oplus 8$$
   $$3^2 \otimes \bar 3^2 =27 \oplus 10 \oplus \bar{10} \oplus 2 (1) \oplus 4(8)$$
   Say, in the 1st case, 2nd and 3rd case, we denote, the objects obtained from multiplications of SU(3) fundamentals (also anti-fundamentals) as:
   $$w_a \otimes w_b \equiv W_{ab} $$
   $$w_a \otimes \bar w_b \equiv W_{a \bar b}$$
   $$w_a \otimes w_b\otimes w_c \otimes w_d  \equiv W_{ab \bar c \bar d} $$

> My question: Which **subgroup** of SU(3) are these objects, (here $W_{ab}$,  $W_{a \bar b}$, and $ W_{ab \bar c \bar d}$ respectively), **invariant** under within each sector of their multiplication decomposition of simple Lie groups irreducible Representations?
>   (say they are in part of their own decompositions, respectively, in  $3 \oplus 6$, in $1 \oplus 8$, and in $27 \oplus 10 \oplus \bar{10} \oplus 2 (1) \oplus 4(8)$?) In particular, are there are some finite subgroup factors?